# SQL UPDATE with PHP variables mysqli_affected_rows

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to allow users to Update their details/entry.

My Php code:

```
include_once('connect/database_connect2.php');

$sql="UPDATE advert_table SET for_sale = '$for_sale', sale_amount = '$sale_amount', seeking = '$seeking', advert_text = '$advert_text', contact_preference = '$contact' WHERE advert_id = '$e'";
if($up_date = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql))
{
    print_r($up_date);
    var_dump($up_date);

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) >= 1)
    {
        print'<div style="border:1px solid #0066FF; padding:5px 5px 5px 20px;   width:96%; background-color:#F0F0F0; ">';
        print'<p>Your add was Updated succesfully <a href="member_zone.php?m=myadds"><img style="padding:5px;vertical-align:middle;"src="./images/ok.png" alt="ok" /></a></p>';
        print'</div>';
    }
}   
else
{
    print'<div style="border:1px solid #0066FF; padding:5px 5px 5px 20px; width:96%; background-color:#F0F0F0; ">';
    print'<p>Unable to Update Entry <a href="somewhere.php?m=myadds"><img style="padding:5px;vertical-align:middle;"src="./images/ok.png" alt="ok" /></a></p>';
    print'</div>';  
}
```

All variables have been duly escaped and sanitized before arriving to the $sql.

I have checked the connection and it is established.

I have checked the variables and they exist, and are the format they are in the database. 
$update gives a 1 YES Boolean as result.

But database is not updated, and no Notification of the If or Else comes out. 
I cannot see my error.
Can anyone help ?

Thank you.

Comment: Anything in the error logs?

Comment: Then apparently no record matches your WHERE clause.

Comment: I used if (!mysqli_query($dbc,$sql)) {
   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbc));} and no errors.

Comment: It is entirely possible for the query to succeed with no errors, and nothing gets updated.  If, say, advert_id = '$e' is not exactly equal.  Are you sure there are no trailing spaces, or anything?  Not only in your input, but the existing row itself.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` to `mysqli_query()`. If any errors, come back and tell us what those are.

Comment: my value $e was coming from my $_GET. Indeed, it was a string and not a number. I used, however, settype($e, "integer"); did a var_dump($e); it was an integer, and the number expected, and still did not work. So $e, exists as it should. Excellent observation though, thank you.

Comment: no errors. $up_date = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbc))

Comment: Could you show your table structure for `advert_table`?

Comment: advert_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  entry_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
  category VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  sub_category VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  for_sale VARCHAR(10),
  sale_amount INT(10) UNSIGNED,
  seeking VARCHAR(10),
  advert_text TEXT NOT NULL,
  num_viewings INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL

Comment: Ok, so the problem is the $e. VolkerK and durbnpoisn were correct. My $e variable comes from another page via <a href=\"page .php?m=myadds_edit&e=$add_id\" >edit</a> for the $_GET on the target page this UPDATE is supposed to be working on. The variable $add_id comes from $add_id=$row['advert_id']; (from my former Query). When I do a var_dump, the number is there, an it is also in the GET variable on target page, but somehow, upon arriving to the SQL clause, it doesn´t work. Putting the literal number in the place of the $e variable DOES work. Why? What am I doing wrong ?Thanks

Comment: My error was I was sending the request back to the same page two times, and on the second time omitting to pass the variable over to the executing code. I thought the first page, with the initial $_GET[ ]; would maintain the value of the variable. Posting the second time, the variable was now gone. Thus, no $e, no nothing. Problem solved with <input type="hidden" name="get_val" value="$e"> now the value of $_GET['e']of the first round submit is in the second $_POST. Thanks to all who offered help and good advice.